# Clip CGPath and fill with two different colours

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, core-graphics

I'm in the process of creating a custom 'star' control in that you would be able to pass a float into the control as the rating i.e. 2.5, and 2.5 out of 5 stars would be coloured red and the rest, gray.

I'm drawing the stars using a UIBezierPath with 5 points and this is working perfectly. However, as I am using floats, I need to make sure that the decimals are taken into account. I thought that the best way to accomplish this would be by clipping the bezier path to a proportion of the final width, however, this method doesn't seem to have any effect on the drawing itself; the stars are drawn as normal, not taking into account the decimals.

As you probably expected me to say, I have indeed only just started dabbling in CoreGraphics and would like an explanation as to why my method doesn't work and a method to fix it, in order to help with my progression through the framework.

Look forward to hearing some responses!

```
- (void)drawStarsWithRating:(float)rating maxRating:(float)maxRating yOrigin:(CGFloat)yOrigin inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    float width = MKRGlyphSize;

    CGFloat xCenter = MKRLeftBorderPadding + (0.5 * width);
    CGFloat yCenter = yOrigin + (0.5 * width);

    double r = width / 2.0;
    float flip = -1.0;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < maxRating; i++) {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        if (i < rating) {
            if (self.selected) {
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, RGB(125, 212, 67).CGColor);
            }
            else {
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, RGB(215, 35, 32).CGColor);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (self.selected) {
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
            }
            else {
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, RGB(178, 178, 178).CGColor);
            }
        }

        double theta = 2.0 * M_PI * (2.0 / 5.0);
        UIBezierPath *bezier = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [bezier moveToPoint:CGPointMake(xCenter, r * flip + yCenter)];

        for (NSUInteger k = 1; k < 5; k++) {
            float x = r * sin(k * theta);
            float y = r * cos(k * theta);
            [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + xCenter, y * flip + yCenter)];
        }
        [bezier setLineWidth:1.0f];
        [bezier setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinMiter];
        [bezier closePath];
        [bezier fill];
        if (rating - floorf(rating) > 0) {
            CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(xCenter, yOrigin, width * (rating - floorf(rating)), width);
            CGContextClipToRect(context, clipRect);
        }
        xCenter += width;
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using drawing is overkill. Unless you're doing this to enhance your skills, I'd suggest using one of the many available star rating controls. If you're doing it on your own, stay away from drawing, that's not the right way.

Comment: The control is going to be in a custom drawn table view cell, so unfortunately this is the only way

Comment: Nope, you can still have the thing working without drawing.

Comment: That's an awful way of doing it, there's no point adding a control as a subview when everything else is being drawn.

Comment: To the contrary, it's awful to draw something when you already have an open source control available. And tbh, having a table view cell where everything is being draw is extremely inefficient and just bad practice in general.

Comment: Open source controls often have bugs and issues with them and further not all are tested. Would you really argue that it's awful to create your own control in that sense? Moreover consistent use of third party libraries will cause a decline in creativity as all apps will begin to look the same. Why's it bad practice - if you're going to make a statement like that, at least back it up.

Comment: Use a reputable control? Anyways, your own version is incomplete, so you cannot comment on the state of other versions, can you? And who said you can't customise an open source control? It's bad practice because you are redrawing ALL of your cell every time it's reused.

Comment: What classifies a reputable control, even AFNetworking has issues. I'm aware that my own version is incomplete, that's why I have asked for a more experienced hand in this area. I can indeed comment on the state of other versions, it's better to do due diligence on the other person before making a comment like that. The number of popular open-source controls I have created far outweigh the intelligence of your argument.

Comment: https://github.com/erndev/EDStarRating Here. Use this and be done with it.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: And that's why it's a comment.

Comment: doing your own drawing can be very good for performance. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606606/fast-scrolling-table-cells-with-images-is-this-how-it-is-done

Comment: It is hard to tell when drawing is faster and when view/layer composition. But in this case I say, you should have one view that draws one star or uses CAShapeLayer and place 5 views next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I noticed is that you `[fill]` the path only once. this means for fractional stars you would've only seen one half of the star and not the other half. In the code below, each star is filled with white, and then if any portion of the star is within the rating, then it is filled again with blue.

I also noticed that the clipping rectangle you were using started its X at `xCenter` instead instead of the lefthand side of the star.

I also adjusted the math a bit to calculate the % filled for each star more consistently.

```
 - (void)drawStarsWithRating:(float)rating maxRating:(float)maxRating yOrigin:(CGFloat)yOrigin inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    float width = MKRGlyphSize;

    CGFloat xCenter = MKRLeftBorderPadding + (0.5 * width);
    CGFloat yCenter = yOrigin + (0.5 * width);

    double r = width / 2.0;
    float flip = -1.0;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < maxRating; i++) {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        // for clarity, i removed the colors from the top
        // and ignore selected state. i use blue/white
        // colors hard coded below
        //
        // you can easily change those colors just as you
        // had before

        // create star path
        double theta = 2.0 * M_PI * (2.0 / 5.0);
        UIBezierPath *bezier = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [bezier moveToPoint:CGPointMake(xCenter, r * flip + yCenter)];
        for (NSUInteger k = 1; k < 5; k++) {
            float x = r * sin(k * theta);
            float y = r * cos(k * theta);
            [bezier addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + xCenter, y * flip + yCenter)];
        }
        [bezier setLineWidth:1.0f];
        [bezier setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinMiter];
        [bezier closePath];

        // fill background of star with white
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        [bezier fill];

        // calculate the percentage of this star
        // that we should fill
        CGFloat currStar = i;
        CGFloat percentOfStar;
        if(rating > currStar){
            // at least some of the star should be filled
            percentOfStar = rating - currStar > 0 ? rating - currStar : 0;
            percentOfStar = percentOfStar > 1 ? 1 : percentOfStar;
        }else{
            // none of the star should be filled
            percentOfStar = 0;
        }
        if (percentOfStar) {
            // if we need at least a little filling, then clip to that % of the star
            // notice (xCenter - .5*width) to align the clipRect to the left side of
            // the star.
            // now fill the selected portion of the star with blue
            CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(xCenter - .5*width, yOrigin, width * (percentOfStar), width);
            CGContextClipToRect(context, clipRect);
            [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
            [bezier fill];
        }
        xCenter += width;
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it slightly differently:

fill the background of your view with the background color

Use the percentOfStar to create a rectangle path that reflects the rating.

Use the star path to clip.